# Debian Linux - “hcitool scan” does not find devices

Tags: linux, debian, bluetooth

I use free VMware player with Debian 7 image.
I use Cambridge Silicone Radio Bluetooth USB adapter
"hciconfig" shows me two interfaces 
(I don't know why two, and I don't know with which I should work):

```
            hci0
            hci1
```

Okay, I did

```
            hciconfig hci0 piscan
            hciconfig hci1 piscan
```

Very good. "Debian-1" bluetooth device is found from my phone.

Then I set  my phone's and tablet's bluetooth as discoverable and run

```
            hcitool scan
```

No results.
Okay, I scan after:

```
            hciconfig hci0 noscan
            hciconfig hci1 noscan
```

No scan results again.

I found some advice 
[here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/781556).
I ran:

```
             bccmd psset -s 0x0000 0x028c 0x0001
```

I could not understand  what it means though.
Well, I got a message "unsupported manufacturer"

I have no any more ideas.
Thanks in advance